# Proxy the http and https traffic from my iPhone/iPad to VirtualBox on my Mac

Tags: ios, networking, proxy, virtualbox, portforwarding

I've got a mac running a Debian VirtualBox which forward the traffic from 8080 on the mac to 80 in the box and from 8443 to 443.

The domains with the extension `.dev` are redirected on the mac to `127.0.0.1` with `dnsmasq`.

The traffic on IP `127.0.0.1` is forwarded from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 8443 using `ipfw`.

So with this settings, my Debian VirtualBox gets all the traffic of my `.dev` domains in http or https.

What I want is to be able to proxy the traffic of my `.dev` domains in http and https from my iPad to my Debian VirtualBox on the mac.

I've try to setup an HTTP proxy on the ipad but I can only do it for one port (and it's not working with the port 443).

Any idea on how I could achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same issue as yours..

There is another option using SquidMan as a http proxy.
Here is some general guide on using squidman:

1. install and start squidman on OSX
2. Set your proxy server port to 8080
3. Add your ip address of your iphone as a Client, aka whitelisting your iphone.
4. comment out the line "http_access deny to_localhost"
5. indicate the location of your host file with "hosts_file /etc/hosts", mine was "/etc/hosts", yours may be different!

I had bind9 setup instead of using the host file the re-route my *.dev urls, so my config was a little bit different.

If you are also using a local DNS like bind9, make sure to add to squid config your dns address.

```
# dns_nameservers
dns_nameservers 127.0.0.1
```

About the https part, the iphone does not allow you to enter a seperate proxy server for https. But, You do not have to configure the https proxy on the iphone. It will automatically use the same server you configured for http proxy for https(443).

see reference http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use Charles.
Here is an blog post which explain how to do this : http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/ipad-http-debugging/

Anyone know how to do this with a command line ?